# Searching an array for a value faster than np.where(ar==value) using fortran and f2py

Tags: python, numpy, search, fortran

I was trying to locate the index of a value on a numpy array (same for hundreds of them) using np.where. Its not that slow but its a bottleneck so i began experimenting with fortran and f2py and wrote this simple routine.

```
subroutine find_index(array1, num_elements, target_value, loc)
    real, intent(in) :: array1(:)
    integer, intent(in) :: num_elements, target_value
    integer, intent(out) :: loc
    do i = 1, num_elements
        if (array1(i) .eq. target_value) then
            loc = i
            exit
        endif
    end do
end subroutine
```

But still no improvement (same as np.where). So i guess its about the method. any sugestions on improving the code (python or fortran)?

**EDIT**
the values i am searching for are integers in an array of integers

Comment: something like y = minloc(abs(array1 - target_value))  and checking whether or not array(y) == target_value. Note that comparisons with floating point values should be done with a small delta!

Comment: Why do ypu think cslling Fortran would be any faster? Surely numpy routines are implemented in C or Fortran and thoroughly optimized.

Comment: also i clarified in the answer that the values are integers i am searching for

Comment: array1 is still of type real.

Comment: You didn't say which Fortran compiler you intend; ifort should be able to vectorize the code you show.  That should be significantly faster than minloc() or even findloc() (an f2008 intrinsic).  As Vladimir said, you should be able to find numpy implementations which do the same.  If num_elements exceeds 100000, you should be able to gain by splitting the array to search in parallel, then finishing by combining the results.  If you are doing several hundred small arrays, likewise you should be able to gain by calling your function in multiple threads.

Comment: gfortran on ubuntu linux.

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT SCREAM WITH CAPITAL LETTERS! Variable `array1` in the code you show is declared `real` no matter how big letters you use.

Comment: Since you are searching for the 1st, it should be faster.  `where` will iterate 3 times to find all.

Comment: the array input are integers. ill change up  the real part. sorry for the screams :)

Comment: Are your arrays sorted? How long are each of your arrays? Will each array only be searched once? Are the searches and results independent from each other?

Comment: in some cases yes while in others no.

Answer (score 1):

It's been sometime since I worked with fortran and f2py, but I did something similar with `cython` last year.

In a Hungarian algorithm search problem, I needed to find the first 0 value in a 2d array, subject to row and column masking arrays.

So using `where` (`argwhere` is just `np.transpose(np.where(...))`, the function was:

```
def find_a_zero(self):
    # find first uncovered 0 cost
    rc = np.argwhere((self.cost + self.rc[:,None] + self.cc) == 0)
    if rc.shape[0]>0:
        return tuple(rc[0])
    else:
        return None, None
```

I got a good speedup with `argmax`:

```
def find_a_zero(self):
    # big help time wise, 16->10 for n=200
    cond = (self.cost + self.rc[:,None] + self.cc) == 0
    if np.count_nonzero(cond):
        idx = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(cond), cond.shape)
        return idx
    return None, None
```

`np.where` uses `count_nonzero` to determine the size of its return arrays.  `argmax`, when operating on a boolean, short circuits on the fist `True`.

I got even better speed with this `cython` version:

```
cdef find_a_zero(int[:,:] cost, int[:] row_cover, int[:] col_cover):
    n = cost.shape[0]
    m = cost.shape[1]
    cdef size_t r, c
    for r in range(n):
        for c in range(m):
            if (cost[r,c]==0) and (row_cover[r]==0) and (col_cover[c]==0):
                row = r
                col = c
                return r, c
    return -1, -1
```

If my memory of `cython` is correct, definitions like `int[:,:] cost` invoke its typed memoryview. which has efficient lowlevel array operations.

http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html

http://csclab.murraystate.edu/~bob.pilgrim/445/munkres.html