# Increasing the speed of finding an index of an item in list

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to speed up a program I've written, and after importing cProfile, I see that one function takes up a massive bit of computation time.

It's this, which finds an numpy.ndarray in a list:

```
    def locate(arr, l ):
        for i in range(len(l)):
            if np.all(l[i] == arr):
                return i
        return -1
```

As the list can't be ordered etc, I can't see any way to avoid scanning the entire list. I have read some pieces on vectorisation, and I wanted to know if that could be applied here, or if there's any other way to speed this up?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be `np.any(l[i] == arr)` instead of `np.all(l[i] == arr)`?

Comment: give us some idea of the dimensions.  Is `arr` the array, and `l` a list of matching shape arrays?

Comment: Looking at the answers I think you need to give a working example. It's too easy to make assumptions that might not apply.

Comment: Your code short-circuits, returning as soon as it finds a match.  It will scan the whole list is there isn't a match.  So timing depends a lot on where the find is, early or late.  Searches that treat `l` as an array (1 higher dimension than `arr`) will scan the whole array (more than once).  They can be faster, if the find is late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably cannot avoid walking the list but you can speed up the comparison:

Set up example:

```
L  = list(np.floor(np.outer(*2*(np.linspace(1,10,1000),))))
arr = L[537]
```

Direct method for reference:

```
import itertools as it

next(it.chain((i for i, a in enumerate(L) if np.all(arr==a)), (-1,)))
# 537
timeit(lambda: next(it.chain((i for i, a in enumerate(L) if np.all(arr==a)), (-1,))), number=100)
# 0.27100146701559424
```

Approach 1: Use `np.array_equal` (slower)

```
next(it.chain((i for i, a in enumerate(L) if np.array_equal(arr, a)), (-1,)))
# 537
timeit(lambda: next(it.chain((i for i, a in enumerate(L) if np.array_equal(arr, a)), (-1,))), number=100)
# 0.2992244770284742
```

Approach 2: Use void view (faster)

```
arr_v = arr.reshape(-1).view(f'V{arr.itemsize*arr.size}')

next(it.chain((i for i, a in enumerate(L) if arr_v==a.reshape(-1).view(f'V{a.itemsize*a.size}')), (-1,)))
# 537
timeit(lambda: next(it.chain((i for i, a in enumerate(L) if arr_v==a.reshape(-1).view(f'V{a.itemsize*a.size}')), (-1,))), number=100)
# 0.11853155982680619
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to implement the void view approach but I'm a bit confused. As I understand it in your example, L is my list of numpy arrays and arr is the numpy array i'm searching for. However I get an error for a.reshape that 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape', even though I assumed a would be a numpy array. Am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: @cucumber Nope, you are understanding it right. `L` is supposed to be a list of arrays as you say. Your getting that error suggests that you are using an `L` that does somehow contain lists?

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in python function called `index()` where you can use it by plugging a string in as the value and finding its index in the list.

Comment: Try 'the_index = l.index(arr)' . This will return the index number, or throw ValueError exception if arr is not in l.

Comment: @hpaulj nope, if by "array elements" you mean arrays which are elements of a list.

Answer (score 0):

So are you looking for `np.where`

```
temp_list=np.array(temp_list)
np.where(temp_list==5)
(array([1, 3, 6, 8]),)
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to Check if a Matrix is in a List of Matrices Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636882/how-to-check-if-a-matrix-is-in-a-list-of-matrices-python)

Here the accepted answer uses `np.array_equal` which first checks shape, then does the `all(==)` test.

Another SO: [Check if 2d array exists in 3d array in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50146279/check-if-2d-array-exists-in-3d-array-in-python)

[Searching an array for a value faster than np.where(ar==value) using fortran and f2py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49208730/searching-an-array-for-a-value-faster-than-np-wherear-value-using-fortran-and)

[Why isn't "numpy.any" lazy (short-circuiting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771554/why-isnt-numpy-any-lazy-short-circuiting)